# My function is returning an empty list and I don't understand why?

Tags: python

I am writing a file overlap function that takes two arguments: longestFile and shorterFile. I want to see if two files have the same numbers and if they do, it will append that number to an empty list.
These are the two lists I am using for the program:
[The first file that I am using to compare](http://file:///C:/Users/Johnathan/Documents/primenumbers.txt) and [The second file that I use](http://file:///C:/Users/Johnathan/Documents/happynumbs.txt)

```
def longestFile(firstFile, secondFile):
    if len(firstFile)>len(secondFile):
       return firstFile
    else:
       return secondFile

def shortestFile(firstFile, secondFile):
    if len (firstFile) < len(secondFile):
       return firstFile
    else:
       return secondFile

def middleNumber(theLongestFile):
    return theLongestFile[len(theLongestFile)//2]

def fileOverlap(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile):
    lstMatchingNums = []
    lstLongerFile = longestFile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
    lstShortestFile = shortestFile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
    for eachLines in range(len(lstShortestFile)):
        lstLongerFile = longestfile(lstFirstFile,lstSecondFile)
        for eachLine in range(len(lstLongerFile)):
            if lstShortestFile[eachLines] == middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
               lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
               break
            elif lstShortestFile[eachLines] < middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
               lstLongerFile = lstLongerFile[0:len(lstLongerFile)//2+1]
               if len(lstLongerFile) <= 2 and lstLongerFile[0] == lstShortestFile[eachLines]:
                  lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
                  break
               elif middleNumber(lstLongerFile) != lstShortestFile[eachLines] and len(lstLongerFile) <=2:
                  break
            elif lstShortestFile[eachLines] > middleNumber(lstLongerFile):
                lstLongerFile = lstLongerFile[len(lstLongerFile)//2:]
                if len(lstLongerFile) <= 2 and lstLongerFile[0] == lstShortestFile[eachLines]:
                   lstMatchingNums.append(lstShortestFile[eachLines])
                   break
                elif middleNumber(lstLongerFile) != lstShortestFile[eachLines] and len(lstLongerFile) <= 2:
                   break
    return lstMatchingNums

lstHappyNums = open('happynumbs.txt','r')
lstReadingHappyLines = lstHappyNums.readlines()
lstHappyNums.close()
lstPrimeNumsFile = open('primenumbers.txt','r')
lstReadingPrimeLines = lstPrimeNumsFile.readlines()
lstPrimeNumsFile.close()
print(fileOverlap(lstReadingHappyLines,lstReadingPrimeLines))
```

If I was to run this program, it would give me an empty list and I am not sure why.

Comment: What is the content of your input files?  And how do you call `fileOverlap`?

Comment: I expect you mean `eachLine` rather than `eachLines` in your nested loop. But please please use proper Python style, and remove this bizarre "lst" prefix on every variable. Also, looping over `range(len(something))` is almost never the right thing to do; just loop over the thing itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your code fails for lack of input.  It is far from minimal, and you haven't explained what you're trying to do.  Include your traces (with inserted `print` statements) of the intermediate stages.

Comment: It might help us understand this issue more easily if you used hard-coded lists, rather than reading from actual files. Can you reproduce the issue with a pair of short example lists? It may be that using such lists will make the problem obvious to you too, not only to us (this effect is called ["rubber duck debugging"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)). You also need to explain what assumptions you can make about the contents of your two lists. For instance, are they always sorted?